# What exactly happens if I listen to the voices in my head?

Tags: the-secret-world

At the end of each 'chapter' of **The Secret World's** main story quests, there's a sequence in which a disembodied voice calls out to you, asking for your cooperation, and pledging power unimaginable.

At the end of Solomon Island, you are given the opportunity to accept or reject this offer. At the end of Egypt, you can seek 'forgiveness' for unnamed transgressions against the voices. After completing Transylvania, you can repair or destroy the prison in which they are presumably trapped.

Does this choice have any impact? Are there different clothing or cosmetic rewards, or even significant narrative or cinematic differences presented based on these three choices? Do any of the options offer more exposition as to who or what exactly these voices are?

Comment: I just finished the first one and was wondering myself.  (I also couldn't figure out how to reject the offer *anyway*, so I just ended up taking it.)

Comment: should't this question be labeled/tagged "spoiler"?

Answer (score 3):

As more reports from various players who have chosen one side or the other have started to roll in (such as in discussion threads like [this one](http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?t=51260)), as well as accounts from players who have played through the main story multiple times with different choices, there doesn't seem to be any confirmed consequence to these choices at the current time. Or, if there is one, it's subtle enough that nobody's been able to identify it yet.

However, as Funcom *has* stated that they intend for certain choices you make in the game to have consequences later on, it's entirely possible that your choice will affect something in some future content, but that's just speculation.

Answer (score 2):

The consequences of these choices are revealed when you complete the quest atop Orochi tower.

> At the end of the story line you are given an ultimate skill (triggered with the 'Z' button) that produces a large AOE effect and causes you to sprout wings. If you have rejected the gift all three times, these wings are gold in color. If you accepted three times, they are black. A mix of acceptances and rejections produces gives you blue or purple wings. These are only cosmetic changes. The effect of the attack is the same regardless.